# Range.Find() text with carriage return Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, find, carriage-return

**What I'm trying to do** 
Locate the column whose header cell contains a unique string. In other words, I know the cell's text, and I know the cell is in row 1, but I don't know which column. NOTE: I want to search for the *entire* text, not just part of it. NOTE2: The text can vary, so I cannot hardcode the *value* into my code. Rather I need to use the *variable* in which the value is stored.

**The problem** 
When there's no carriage return in the header text, a simple `newCol = Range("1:1").Find(headerText).Column` **works fine**. However, if there is a carriage return, this doesn't work. It throws up the error "Object variable or With block variable not set". Here's my exact header string:

```
Incomplete Email
(more text)
```

**What I've already tried** 
I also tried using `WorksheetFunction.Match(headerText, Range("1:1"), 0)`, but got the same issue.

**Additional notes and requirements** 
This is part of an add-in, so I do not want to change anything in the user's excel sheet if I don't have to (i.e., I *don't* want to remove the carriage return).

Technically, I'm doing this in a function:

```
Public Function getColumn(headerText As Variant)
    getColumn = Range("1:1").Find(headerText).Column
End Function
```

Thanks!

Comment: What if you try `Range("1:1").Find("*" & headerText & "*").Column`

Comment: No luck. Same problem

Comment: How did you declare `newCol`? I put "Test [alt-enter] Test" and ran `newCol = Range("1:1").Find("Test").Column` and it worked.

Comment: Did you try `Trim` and `CLEAN`Functions???

Comment: If you are absolutely certain it is in Range (1:1) then you can try `Range("1:1").Find(What:=headerText, LookAt:=xlPart).Column`

Comment: Elbert and LocEngineer: neither solution worked. There are no blank spaces on either end of the string and the string is the entire value of the cell, not just part of it.

Comment: Bruce: Technically, it's the return value of a function. But I'm not surprised yours worked since you looked for a string "Test" with no carriage return in it.

Comment: Stupid question: are you searching for `Incomplete Email` or for `Incomplete Email
(more text)` ?

Comment: I'm searching for the whole thing: "Incomplete Email (more text)", where there's a carriage return between "Incomplete Email" and "(more text)".

Comment: In that case it just worked for me using `Find(What:="Incomplete Email" & Chr(10) & "(more text)")`

Comment: Right, so that works because you've hardcoded the string and carriage return. But I don't KNOW there will be one. So I need to search for the VARIABLE not the VALUE.

Answer (score 1):

pls try with below code

```
Public Function getColumn(headerText As String)
    str1 = Split(headerText, vbCrLf)
    str2 = UBound(str1)
    b = Range("1:1").Find(str1(0) & Chr(10) & str1(1)).Column
End Function
```

Comment: See BruceWayne's comment above. This does not work. Makes some sense that it would not, since I have the whole string, so the wildcards "*" don't really do much.

Comment: It's not a perfect solution for me, but it can do as a backup. First I'll determine if there's a carriage return and there is, I'll use this code. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's the thing: text with and without line break is NOT the same text hence the `.Find` fail. What you should do is a pattern lookup. I have just tested this and it works, provided that if there is no line break there shall be a space:

```
Sub test()
Dim rex As RegExp, ran As Range
Dim col As Integer, headerText As String

'read you headerText here

Set rex = New RegExp
rex.Pattern = RegexIt(headerText)

For Each ran In Range("1:1")
    If rex.test(ran.Text) Then
        col = ran.Column
        Exit For
    End If
Next ran

MsgBox col

End Sub

Function RegexIt(what As String) As String

what = Replace(what, "(", "\(")
what = Replace(what, ")", "\)")
what = Replace(what, "[", "\[")
what = Replace(what, "]", "\]")
what = Replace(what, "<", "\<")
what = Replace(what, ">", "\>")
what = Replace(what, " ", "[\n ]?")
what = Replace(what, vbCrLf, "[\n ]?")

End Function
```

Good luck!

**Edit:** Reference to Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5 required

**Edit2:** Edited for variable use. Explanation: Replace space in variable value with optionel space/line break, escape brackets for pattern matching.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, as I've mentioned above, I need to search for the variable because the exact string can vary. Can you use RegEx with a variable?

Comment: Provided breaks can only happen in between words of the variable value, yes. See edit2.

Comment: This seems more intuitive, but also more clunky than Karthick's solution above.

Comment: It definitely looks more clunky. But Kathick's won't work if there is NO line break. Also my code above contained errors. I have amended it a bit and also extended for when the headertext contains spaces or line breaks or characters that need to be escaped for regex. Should do fine though.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work even if the header cell contains carriage returns:

```
Sub FindColumnWithTextInRowOne()
    Dim headerText As String, newCol As Long

    headerText = "whatever"
    newCol = Range("1:1").Find(headerText).Column
    MsgBox newCol
End Sub
```

[image]

This is because your use of *Find()* does not require a match to the WHOLE contents of the cell.

**EDIT#1:**

If the header cell was constructed using a *formula*, then a slightly different `Find()` should be used:

```
   Sub FindColumnWithTextInRowOne()
    Dim headerText As String, newCol As Long, r As Range
    headerText = Range("H1").Text
    newCol = Range("1:1").Find(What:=headerText, LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues).Column
    MsgBox newCol
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: You're searching for part of the header text, not the whole thing.

Comment: Try searching for Range("H1").Value, or wherever you have that text stored. It shouldn't work.

Comment: No such luck, although things are slightly different. Because I'm working with a form, headerText is actually the value of a dropdown/combobox that's passed to the function. Using the `LookAt:=xlWhole` and `Lookin:=xlValues` didn't help.